# Starting with Android 12, multicasting to a group of BLE audio headphones is supported. How this can be achieved?

Tags: audio, bluetooth-lowenergy, audio-streaming

Connecting 2 bluetooth devices at once to your android device and stream audio simultaneously for both of them.

combined audio device routing
https://source.android.com/docs/core/audio/combined-audio-routing

in aosp source code page it is mentioned about ble audio supporting multiple audio sink devices....
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/ble-audio/overview

Comment: On which topic do you need elaboration on? You posted a source from android which states that your usecase is possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.